# HTL-Maven plugin is not working in AEM 6.2

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

I want to use htl-maven-plugin to validate HTL syntax.
I am using the plugin shown below:

```
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>htl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate-scripts</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>validate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root</sourceDirectory>
                    <failOnWarnings>true</failOnWarnings>
                    <includes>**/*.html</includes>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But it's not validating my HTL part and make the build success.
Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your `sourceDirectory` is not properly configured. Are your sources really in `ui.apps/src/main/content/jcr_root`? If not, please update the configuration!

If your project is structured as:

- reactor

  - ui.apps

    - src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/..
    - pom.xml
  - ui.content
  - ..

The `sourceDirectory` in `ui.apps/pom.xml` should be configured to `src/main/content/jcr_root` (relative to `ui.apps` module `pom`)

Also, running `mvn htl:validate` from the command line in `ui.apps` module will give you a bit more information about what is happening. You should see either:

- `[INFO] Source directory does not exist, skipping.` - source directory is not configured properly.
- `[INFO] Processed .. files in .. milliseconds` - source is configured, files were processed

For more documentation please also refer to http://sling.apache.org/components/htl-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: Hi Viad, When i am clicking on source directory,it is taking me to right directory but when i am trying mvn htl:validate it is showing: 

"htl-maven-plugin:1.0.6:validate (default-cli) @ bhf-reactor.ui.apps ---
[INFO] Source directory does not exist, skipping."

Comment: @ArpitRathi, your IDE might be -smart- about it. I added a few more details in my answer, HTH